# Upload file in SQL database using BCP command

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I want to save file in remote database from local machine where file is located. I want to achieve this using BCP command. How can this be achieved?

My query is similar to the below:

```
INSERT INTO ExcelFileUploadedData(
    Project, 
    SubProject, 
    LogicalName,FileName, 
    FileData) 

SELECT 
    'Sample',
    'Sample',
    'BP',
    '1.xls',
    * 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\File\File1.xls.zip', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

Comment: This seems to be the right syntax assuming you want to just store the binary file in a varbinary(max) field called "FileData". What error are you receiving?

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this because BULK load using OPENROWSET requires the file on the local database server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    SET @TableQuery='CREATE TABLE [temp1](
             [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
             Project [NVARCHAR(50)], 
             SubProject [NVARCHAR(50)], 
             LogicalName [NVARCHAR(50)],
             FileName [NVARCHAR(50)], 
             FileData [NVARCHAR(50)],
             CONSTRAINT [PK_temp1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
             (
                [Id] ASC
              )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
              ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
                                                '
             EXEC(@TableQuery)  

             DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(max)
             SET @params = N'@uploadData SINGLE_BLOB readonly'

             SET @BulkInsertQuery =N'INSERT INTO [temp1] ( Project,            SubProject,LogicalName,FileName,FileData) 
select * from @uploadData';          
             print @BulkInsertQuery
             EXEC sp_executesql @BulkInsertQuery, @params, @uploadData

    // Enter Records from temp table into real table

             INSERT INTO ExcelFileUploadedData(
                Project, 
                SubProject, 
                LogicalName,FileName, 
                FileData) 
             SELECT 
                'Sample',
                'Sample',
                'BP',
                '1.xls',
                * 
         FROM [temp1]
```